# Extrema of $\cos(\alpha)\cos(\theta+\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\cos(\theta-\beta)$

Tags: trigonometry

Is this solvable? (No calculus)

If angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given, for all values of $\theta$, find the maximum and minimum values of $$\cos(\alpha)\cos(\theta+\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\cos(\theta-\beta)$$

When $\beta$, $\alpha-\frac\pi 4$ are not odd multiples of $\pi/2$, corresponding $\theta$ of maximum value satisfy the equation $$\tan(\theta)=\tan(\beta)\tan\left(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

I used calculus to get the last result, but the problem is you cannot use calculus. I couldn't find the maximum and minimum either. Any explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos(\alpha)\cos(\theta+\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\cos(\theta-\beta)$$ $$= (\cos \alpha +\sin \alpha)\cos \beta \cos \theta + (-\cos \alpha +\sin \alpha)\sin \beta \sin \theta $$ (compound angle identities) $$= \sqrt{2}\cos (\alpha -\tfrac{1}{4}\pi)\cos \beta \cos \theta + \sqrt{2}\sin (\alpha -\tfrac{1}{4}\pi)\sin \beta \sin \theta $$ (compound angle identities again)$$=R \cos(\theta -\gamma)$$ if $R^2=2\cos^2 (\alpha -\tfrac{1}{4}\pi)\cos^2 \beta  + 2\sin^2 (\alpha -\tfrac{1}{4}\pi)\sin^2 \beta$ and $$\tan\gamma = \frac{\sin (\alpha -\tfrac{1}{4}\pi)\sin \beta }{\cos (\alpha -\frac{1}{4}\pi)\cos \beta }= \tan(\alpha -\tfrac{1}{4}\pi) \tan \beta$$
(because you want  $R\cos \gamma = \sqrt{2}\cos (\alpha -\frac{1}{4}\pi)\cos \beta $ and $R\sin \gamma = \sqrt{2}\sin(\alpha -\frac{1}{4}\pi)\sin \beta $).

Then the maximum is $R$, and this occurs when $\theta = \gamma$.

Answer (score -1):

You can rewrite it as: $f(\theta) = a\cos \theta + b\sin \theta\implies f^2(\theta) = (a\cos \theta+b\sin \theta)^2 \le (a^2+b^2)(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)= a^2+b^2\implies -\sqrt{a^2+b^2}= f_{\text{min}} \le f \le f_{\text{max}}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, where $a = \cos(\alpha - \beta), b = \sin\beta(\sin \alpha - \cos \alpha)$.